# Eav Attributes options

Tags: magento2, attributes, eav

Script below add new eav attribute to product model. But who can explain me what mean everyone option in third paramater from function `addAttribute()` and where it using or give some links where i can read something about it.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
private $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'sample_attribute',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
            'input' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
}
}
```